# Connect two Broadband (PPPOE) at the same time

Tags: networking, windows-8, pppoe

I have two Ethernet adapter in my laptop (running Windows 8), two Networking cable from hub (for same ISP) and two pair of user name and password to connect to internet using Broadband (PPPOE) technology. I want to connect both Broadband Connection at the same time. Normally windows doesn't allow me to connect to the second broadband connection while the first one is connected. It shows the following error:

> You have attempted to establish a second broadband connection while a
>   previous broadband connection is already established ...

Is there any way I can choose which Ethernet adapted to be used for which Broadband Connection (PPPOE) and have two active connections at the same time?

I appreciate any suggestion, Thanks :)